# partykit object varid mismatch

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I am using `partykit` and noticed a possible `varid` mismatch (unless I misunderstood something). Below is the example code.

The root node as returned by `nodeapply` shows variable 5 as the split variable.

Also the first element of the explicitly generated list has `split$varid` 5. If we look at the `iris` data frame then the 5th column is `Species`, and `Petal.Width` is 4th column which should be the `varid` for the root node as shown by the `j48_party` object.

It seems like the `varid` are actual feature used +1, is this intentional?

```
> library(partykit)
> library(RWeka)
> data("iris")
> j48 <- J48(Species~., data=iris)
> j48_party <- as.party(j48)
> j48_party

Model formula:
Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (n = 50, err = 0.0%)
|   [3] Petal.Width > 0.6
|   |   [4] Petal.Width <= 1.7
|   |   |   [5] Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (n = 48, err = 2.1%)
|   |   |   [6] Petal.Length > 4.9
|   |   |   |   [7] Petal.Width <= 1.5: virginica (n = 3, err = 0.0%)
|   |   |   |   [8] Petal.Width > 1.5: versicolor (n = 3, err = 33.3%)
|   |   [9] Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (n = 46, err = 2.2%)

Number of inner nodes:    4
Number of terminal nodes: 5
> colnames(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
> nodeapply(j48_party)
$`1`
[1] root
|   [2] V5 <= 0.6 *
|   [3] V5 > 0.6
|   |   [4] V5 <= 1.7
|   |   |   [5] V4 <= 4.9 *
|   |   |   [6] V4 > 4.9
|   |   |   |   [7] V5 <= 1.5 *
|   |   |   |   [8] V5 > 1.5 *
|   |   [9] V5 > 1.7 *

> nodes <- as.list(j48_party$node)
> nodes[[1]]$split$varid
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is due to the following: `J48()` like most other modeling functions (such as `lm()`, `glm()`, etc.) does not simply directly use the `data` supplied but first builds up a `model.frame`. This already carries out variable transformations (e.g., taking logs, creating factors or `Surv()` objects), collecting variables that might not be in `data` but in the calling environment, and leaving out variables that are not in the model `formula` etc. See `?model.frame` for further information and links.

Therefore, the object created by `J48()` has a `model.frame` that is not exactly the `iris` data but the response variable was moved to the first column:

```
head(model.frame(j48))
##   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
## 1  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
## 2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
## 3  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
## 4  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
## 5  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
## 6  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

And the information from this is also carried over to the `party` object.

```
j48_party$data
## [1] Species      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width 
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

[Note: In the case of `J48()` this only stores the meta-information but drops the actual data because it is not needed here. But this is different for `ctree()` for example.]

To see that this `model.frame()` can be different from the original data consider the following situation: we create a new `noise` variable that is *not* part of `iris` but just in the calling environment, take logs, and omit several variables:

```
set.seed(1) 
noise <- rnorm(150)
j48 <- J48(Species ~ log(Petal.Width) + noise, data = iris)
j48_party <- as.party(j48)
head(model.frame(j48))
##   Species log(Petal.Width)      noise
## 1  setosa       -1.6094379 -0.6264538
## 2  setosa       -1.6094379  0.1836433
## 3  setosa       -1.6094379 -0.8356286
## 4  setosa       -1.6094379  1.5952808
## 5  setosa       -1.6094379  0.3295078
## 6  setosa       -0.9162907 -0.8204684
j48_party$data
## [1] Species          log(Petal.Width) noise           
## <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification and quick response.